# react native + redux - Expected a component class, got [object Object]

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I am getting started with building react native apps (with redux). I was following examples from different blogs and was able to put together a simple app with a login page to get started. However I am getting, `expected a component class, got [object Object]` error. Would appreciate if someone can point out what is wrong in my code.

**demoApp/index.ios.js**

```
import React, { AppRegistry } from 'react-native';
import DemoApp from './app/';

AppRegistry.registerComponent('demoApp', () => DemoApp);
```

**demoApp/app/index.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import App from './containers/App';
import rootReducer from './reducers/rootReducer';

const store = createStore(rootReducer);

export default class DemoApp extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  };

  render () {
    return (
      <Provider store = { store }>
        <App />
      </Provider>
    );
  };
};
```

**demoApp/app/containers/App.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import {
  View,
} from 'react-native';
import Login from '../containers/Login';

export class App extends Component {
  componentWillMount() {
    // this is the first point of control after launch
  };

  render() {
    if (this.props.signedIn) {
      return <Login />
    } else {
      return <Login />
    }
  };
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    signedIn: false;
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(App);
```

**demoApp/app/containers/Login/index.js**

```
// Container for Login Component
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import Login from './Login';

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    isLoggedIn: false,
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Login);
```

**demoApp/app/containers/Login/Login.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  View,
  Text
} from 'react-native';
import styles from './styles';
import images from '../../config/images';

export default class Login extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View style = { styles.container }>
        if (this.props.isLoggedIn) {
          <Text style = { styles.welcome }>
            Welcome to Demo App!
          </Text>
        } else {
          <img style = { styles.logoImage } src = { images.logo } alt = "Demo App Logo" />
        }
      </View>
    );
  };
};
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `Login.js`, the return statement is wrong; you cannot mix JSX and Javascript this way. Javascript must be inlined within curly brackets.

Something like this would be better

```
const comp =  this.props.isLoggedIn ? 
    <Text style = { styles.welcome }>
        Welcome to Demo App!
    </Text>
    :
    <img style = { styles.logoImage } src = { images.logo } alt = "Demo App Logo" />


return (
  <View style = { styles.container }>
    {comp}
  </View>
);
```

Comment: Thanks Bruno. That was the issue. I solved it using the `Image` tag of `React`.